# Windows 8.1 update replaces ".co.uk" button with ".com" button

Tags: 8.1, keyboard

I have a UK Lumia 1520 which has recently been upgraded to Windows 8.1 through the Over-the-air update mechanism. The developer preview was not installed on this phone.

The keyboard used to have the ".co.uk" button shown by default, and long-pressing on it would allow other options to be selected. Since the update for 8.1 this has now changed to ".com". I've checked all of the regional settings (keyboard, language, location) and all are set to UK. I can't find any option to change the default.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: Are you using Cortana? It requires the region to be set to US. Maybe this made this option disappear.

Comment: No, I'm not using Cortana. As stated in my original question everything is set to UK. I've a feeling that it's Microsoft reverting back to "ye goode olde days" of US first (where us Brits had to tell the Windows installer about 5 times which country we were in)

Comment: Even if you live in the UK, I doubt the majority of websites you visit are .co.uk, so .com is the default. As long as .co.uk is an option, I don't see the issue.

Comment: I've not seen this behaviour with the developer preview, set to UK

Comment: @NeilTurner Majority of websites that I visit might not be in the UK, but the majority of typing I do (logging in etc) is .co.uk as I have a .co.uk email address. I wouldn't complain about this if it had always been the case, but it _was_ the case for 8.0 (and as Rowland stated the dev preview)

Comment: Understood, but it's likely it was changed due usage stats from the WP8 keyboard - ie. most people were selecting .com.